# How to remain on page after login & log out

Tags: php, authentication

how do i create the below php that the user stays on the index page after logging in ? It seems it will direct the user to the logonprocess.php after clicking the submit button.

I'm also trying to find out how will the logout button appear after the user login successfully. The logout will also need to work the same as login which will stay on the same page.

I have read that ajax was one way but i have not yet read or understand ajax. I'm still trying to learn on the php portion first.

```
Index.php
           <?php
            ini_set("session.save_path", "sessionData");
            session_start();
            ?>

 <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['uName'])) { ?>
    <form method="post" action="logonProcess.php">
    <div>Username <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username"></div>
    <div>Password <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Logon"></div>
    </form>
<?php } else { }?>



<?php if (isset($_SESSION['uName'])) { 
        $username = $_SESSION['uName'];     
    echo "<p>Welcome $username</p>\n";
?>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<?php } else { }?>
```

Logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{    
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: That's because your action points to logonProcess.php, it's doing what it's supposte to, either you can remove the logonProcess.php from the form action or you can redirect back to index.php from the logonProcess once the script has done it's job. (Or simply use AJAX).

Comment: So one way is to put all the user/password authentication logon process within every page ?  because in case the user login at another page, how will the redirecting back to the original page works ?

Comment: See KiwiJuicer's answer, that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect somewhere after a certain script has been executed you could ofcourse always use PHP's [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function which allows you to specify a `Location` which would look like this

`header('Location: index.php');`

After that your part two of the question is "How do I remove the logout button when the user **login** successfully?" I think with **login** you must mean **logout** since you'll want to be able to actually **logout** once **logged in**.

To do this you check wether or not a [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

A [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in PHP is simply an array containing values that are remembered across page reloads so as you can imagine - it is a very good place to store your user ID.

*The reason that usually just an ID is saved is so that while a hacker might still be able to compromise your users' cookie he / she will not be able to see any data he / she shouldn't have like a password, email address, phone number etcetera so all damage done will be on the website itself, not the users personal life ^.^*

When you create a [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in PHP you simply set it in your `logonProces.php` file after all the authentication checks for the user passed.

This would look something like this (*semi-psuedo code*)

```
if ($user_verified_in_db) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user['ID']; //note - non of this will probably exist yet in your script, DONT use it its an EXAMPLE.
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

The above snippet should be placed somewhere appropiate in the `procesLogon.php` file so that the session will be set.

Now in HTML you'll have a link somehwere right?

```
<a href="logout.php" class="..." id="...">Logout</a>
```

Imagine that is your link being displayed somewhere on the page, now what you want to do is check if the `$_SESSION['user']` is set using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Your code would look something like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
    <a href="logout.php" class="..." id="...">Logout</a>
<?php } ?>
```

this will check if the session is set or not, if it isn't set it won't display the link, if it is it will since you'll need an option to logout.

**NOTE** this is psuedo code - you still have to build this construction using **your** variables and **your** login script, my tiny piece of code doesn't do anything for you at that except show you an *example* of how this is commonly handled.

Good luck!

### EDIT (5-11-2015)

As per the comment of the OP,

If you want to hide items in general, like the logout link example above, all you have to do is wrap the divs you want to hide in the if statement.

e.g.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
    <!-- this can be any HTML element showing stuff for logged in users. -->
<?php } ?>
```

when you wrap elements within this `if` statement - if you check the expression: `isset($_SESSION['user'])` - it will evaluate to `true` if `$_SESSION['user']` is set which you are in your login script.

You can keep reusing this check whenever and wherever you need to show / hide elements from the user.

if you would put a `!` (exclamation mark) in front of the expression so that it turns out like this: `!isset($_SESSION['user'])` you reverse the process so if you have the following statement

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
    <!-- everything here is shown when user is logged in -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- everything here is shown when user is logged out -->
} ?>
```

this is the positive if check checking if your user is logged in or not, you can decide to put in the else for what to do when the user isn't logged in but you can also modify the expression slightly to reverse or invert the situation e.g.

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
    <!-- everything here is shown when user is logged out -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- everything here is shown when user is logged in -->
} ?>
```

for instance. This will allow you to gain control over what users see on your webpages, use them whenever you need to show or hide something.

Also note that the `else` clause is ofcourse, optional and doesn't have to be included, you can use the `!` example without the else as well as the one without the exclamation mark.

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful and well explained. I manage to almost get it working well except when after successful login, it was redirect back to the original page with the username & password box is still there. Is there anyway I should use like if login session is true, do not show the username & password box ?

Comment: @DoranL the same code that applies to the logout can also be used around your username and password box, just find the div containing the elements and wrap it with the the PHP code that checks if the user is logged in. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks I understand and the reverse condition also helps. There's just something i like to ask about log out.. the logout.php doesn not accept header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); and after i click on logout button.. it doesn't reflect back to the index.php with the negative condition

Comment: @DoranL on your logout page you do not need to have this condition. The action is already clear, namely *logging __out__* so you don't need any `if` statements, you just `unset($_SESSION['user'])` and use the `header()` function to get back to it, if I am failing to understand you can always open up a new question (after you've looked at other questions if there are any of course) and post the link here :)

Answer (score 4):

At the end of your logonProcess.php file:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

If you login from different pages use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is if there's only index.php & logonprocess.php. But if there's many other php and every php have a login box. These means it won't be able to redirect back to the original page ?

Comment: Store it in the $_SESSION and check if user is logged in.

Comment: If your problem is solved you could tag it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code end of php file logonprocess.php too.

```
echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the `echo "<script>window.location=\'index.php\'</script>"` to an if/else statement within your `logonProcess.php` so that once they "submit" the information it processes and redirects to index.php.